# How to make the Login work when site is hosted online

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have made a Exam Portal with Codeigniter, while I was trying to Login in localhost it was working fine, but why, once I hosted my website for testing on "000Webhost", it's getting stuck on `"index.php/login/verifylogin"` ?

For reference, I am posting my routes.php code:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
$route['404_override'] = 'login/commercial';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file in your root directory?
If not you could try creating one and adding the following:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: @SH_ I did what you asked for and faced this error

{Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@000webhost.io to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.}

Comment: @SH_  In my .htaccess file its like below



<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>

Comment: it's likely the free hosting doesn't allow any user `.htaccess`, contact them to clarify, also please edit your question and explain "*...it's getting stuck on...*", any error messages, error log's browser console network tab messages, etc. would help

Comment: @Vickel  You can check by going on https://quizenterprise.000webhostapp.com/ what error I am getting, first of all Login page is not appearing properly then comes the Login issue its not getting redirected to the Dashboard

Comment: Did you set the `base url` properly ?

Comment: Yes @Dum I have set the base url properly. ($sq_base_url='https://quizenterprise.000webhostapp.com')

Comment: Can you check the server logs and post them here, it would be easier to help you.
You may try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in your php file if don't have access to logs.

Comment: Add all clarifications to your question instead of commenting. Perhaps the foremost problem is that your hosting is gone: https://web.archive.org/web/20240105031537/https://quizenterprise.000webhostapp.com/ — _"The authors have deleted this site."_